# Uploading file using POST request in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to upload a video file to my server using a post request.

```
var file = new File(videoPath);
var uri = Uri.parse(tokenizedUri);
HttpClientRequest request = await new HttpClient().postUrl(uri);

await request.addStream(file.openRead());
var response = await request.close();

response.transform(utf8.decoder).forEach((string) {
  print(string); // handle data
});
```

But the server doesn't get it. Why?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 10):

The correct way is to use a MultipartRequest:

```
    var uri = Uri.parse(url);
    var request = new MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    var multipartFile = await MultipartFile.fromPath("package", videoPath);
    request.files.add(multipartFile);

    StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
      print(value);
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm doing the same thing but not getting the file in server. Here is my code
`request.fields['title'] = title.text;
    request.fields['sub_title'] = subTitle.text;
    var profile_photo =
        await MultipartFile.fromPath("profile_photo", photo.path);
    request.files.add(profile_photo);
    request.files
        .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('profile_video', video.path));
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    print(responseString);
`
{sub_title":"dd","profile_photo":{},"profile_video":{}}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) package. It supports large files and works fine with me.

```
sendFile(String kMainUrl, XFile file) async {
    String filePath = file.path;
    String fileName = 'any name';

    try {
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
        "file":
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(filePath, filename:fileName),
      });
      Response response =
      await Dio().post(kMainUrl, data: formData);
      print("File upload response: $response");
      print(response.data['message']);
    } catch (e) {
      print("Exception Caught: $e");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me if the file size is more than 100 mb? how can we upload it in chunks using dio? please tell me if you know.