# how do I upload video file to server in flutter

Tags: video, server, dart, flutter

I am trying to upload the video selected from gallery to the server.
guide me about this. how can i upload the video to the server.

I have tried http with multipart form data but it didn't work for me as i am not understanding the logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading file using POST request in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999438/uploading-file-using-post-request-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a dedicated media API instead of uploading to your own server, you can do it using [flutter_publitio](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_publitio) - I wrote a full tutorial in [this post](https://www.learningsomethingnew.com/how-to-make-a-cross-platform-video-sharing-app-with-flutter-and-firebase).

Comment: Is there a way to upload video files without firebase?

Comment: Here firebase is used to store a list of the videos to enable sharing the links between users, it's not a necessary part of the video upload.

Comment: This package is discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

**Check out this answer to see how another user uploaded a video from the gallery:** [Flutter- Firebase Storage upload video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822789/flutter-firebase-storage-upload-video)

---

You'll want to use the Firebase Storage Flutter plugin. Check out the following resources to get started:

Flutter firebase_storage repo: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_storage

Example main.dart file showing how to upload and download a file from Firebase: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_storage/example/lib/main.dart

More info on Firebase storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

Answer (score 0):

You can upload all type of file by using dio plugin available on pub.dart

```
var res = await Dio.post("server url", data, {
"media_files[]": list.map((f) =>
         f is File ?
         UploadFileInfo(f, f.path) :
         f is String ?
         UploadFileInfo(File(f), f) :
         null
         ).toList(),

});
```